# How to animate flowing hair using the new hair system?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, hair

I made hair for my character using the new hair system. As it seems that in the new hair system each hair is an individual curve.

I would like to give the hair subtle movements as if it is weightless and floating in the air. How do I go about this? Searched everywhere and did not find any helpful resource.

Would this essentially be animating a curve?

EDIT: it doesn’t need to be a simulation, it could be manually adding keyframes, but it doesn’t seem to allow me to do that

[image]

Comment: Simulation for the new hair system is not yet implemented

Comment: @Emir can I manually edit the hair paths to animate it? I can’t find the option to add keyframes for the hair paths

Comment: *Keyframes* are not available because these curves are geometry like a mesh. You cannot use *Keyframes* for geometry, just *Shape Keys*. But shape keys are not implemented yet for the *Curves* object. And the only supported modifier is a *Geometry Nodes* modifier. You still have a few options here: 1) make a copy of the curves object, edit it and use it as a shape key. Use GN to blend between the shapes. 2) Use GN with a *Noise* texture (or more sophisticated calculations) to get a wiggle/floating effect. 3) Use a dummy/proxy with *Cloth* physics & make the curves follow its movement with GN

Comment: I recommend reducing the number of edited hair curves. Use them as guides with the *Interpolate Hair Curves* asset to create hair children. (It's a GN modifier that is included in Blender 3.6; check the *Asset Browser*). This way you don't have to deal with so many individual hair curves and you can use the GN modifier settings to control how many hair particles you want.

Comment: @Blunder okay, I’ll have a look into that. Thank you very much

Comment: Here is a quick test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d3pe.gif The strands in the upper half are edited hair curves. They are enclosed in a conical mesh that serves as a deformation cage. A Cloth sim deforms it. Then there is a copy of the curves. It's converted into a mesh because the *Mesh Deform* modifier only works with meshes (+ because I didn't know how to sample the cage with GN). Finally, the deformed curves copy is copied to the original curves with a GN modifier. The bottom half shows interpolated hair children. Since there is only 1 strand, it looks a bit unrealistic, but promising